# It is possible to query the IPAddress in QueryActivity

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

It is possible to Query the IPAddress in QueryActivity
iam trying this one but i didnt get IpAddress

select  FromName,FromEmail,IPAddress
 from _Job

Comment: Why do you need the sending IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a Private IP Address, in which the value for this field will be null.

> The IP address used for the job; users with a dedicated private IP
>   address will receive a null value.

It may be worth checking your account config to see if this is the case.